# How can I add my entity to side menu in sales hub?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-uci

I created solution and added entity and form with 3 fields to it, but I can't see my entity in the side menu of the main sales hub.

I tried to add site maps etc, doesn't work.
What could be the problem? maybe something missing in my process?

**My process**: create solution -> add entity -> add field -> click on main form and add fields -> save and publish

UPDATE: Now I found this under 'Extensions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main sitemap is for main app. Sales hub app will have its own sitemap. You have to edit that sitemap to include the navigation item in Sales hub app. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crm365blog/posts/do-you-know-custom-entity-not-show-up-on-uci-dynamics-365-for-sales-hub)

Go to: Dynamics 365 > Settings > Customizations > Model-Driven Apps

Open the App designer and click on the Sitemap editor.

[image]

By default the custom entities will be showing under Settings - Extensions.